# Fabric chaincode - Communicate with Vault

Tags: openssl, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I need to, somehow, communicate with a Vault instance from some chaincode.

My issue is that I need (mutual) TLS on Vault, so in order for the chaincode to communicate with it, it needs the appropriate certificates issued by the appropriate CA.

Both the peer that the chaincode is installed on and the Vault instance, utilize the same root CA.

So, how can I acquire the appropriate certificates in the chaincode and use them for the request made to the Vault instance?

If it, somehow, helps:

**log from the chaincode container when I make the request:**

```
2021-01-21T14:18:29.847Z error [c-api:_]                                          Unhandled Rejection reason RequestError: Error: unable to verify the first certificate promise Promise {
  <rejected> RequestError: Error: unable to verify the first certificate
      at new RequestError (/usr/local/src/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/errors.js:14:15)
      at Request.plumbing.callback (/usr/local/src/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/plumbing.js:87:29)
      at Request.RP$callback [as _callback] (/usr/local/src/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/plumbing.js:46:31)
      at self.callback (/usr/local/src/node_modules/request/request.js:185:22)
      at Request.emit (events.js:311:20)
      at Request.onRequestError (/usr/local/src/node_modules/request/request.js:881:8)
      at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:311:20)
      at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:426:9)
      at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:311:20)
      at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8) {
    name: 'RequestError',
    message: 'Error: unable to verify the first certificate',
    cause: Error: unable to verify the first certificate
        at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1473:34)
        at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:311:20)
        at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:916:8)
        at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:686:12) {
      code: 'UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE'
    },
    error: Error: unable to verify the first certificate
        at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1473:34)
        at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:311:20)
        at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:916:8)
        at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:686:12) {
      code: 'UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE'
    },
    options: {
      json: [Object],
      resolveWithFullResponse: true,
      simple: false,
      strictSSL: true,
      method: 'PUT',
      path: '/sys/unseal',
      headers: [Object],
      uri: 'https://vaultinstance.com:8200/v1/sys/unseal',
      callback: [Function: RP$callback],
      transform: undefined,
      transform2xxOnly: false
    },
    response: undefined
  }
}
```

**log from vault when the request is made:**

```
2021-01-21T14:20:59.784Z [INFO]  http: TLS handshake error from 192.168.224.1:51074: remote error: tls: unknown certificate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to provide secret config information to chaincode at install time so unless you include the certificate in the chaincode package, which is probably a bad idea, so I think your chaincode will need an init transaction to send in the required certificate using transient data.

The [chaincode lifecycle](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/chaincode_lifecycle.html) documentation describes how to require an init transaction.

> If you are using the Fabric peer CLI, you can use the --init-required
> flag when you approve and commit the chaincode definition to indicate
> that the Init function must be called to initialize the new chaincode
> version. To call Init using the Fabric peer CLI, use the peer
> chaincode invoke command and pass the --isInit flag.

The [private data](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/private-data-arch.html) describes how you can protect the TLS certificate when you initialise the chaincode.

Alternatively, if you don't want to use an init transaction or store the TLS certificate on the ledger/in a private data collection, you could provide the TLS certificate using transient data to every transaction which needs to communicate with the vault and leave it to the client to manage the certificate.

Comment: One solution that came to my mind was to actually make some "enrollment" inside the chaincode itself and then keep the generated certificate and key files as private data. One advantage of this would be that I could easily "refresh"/revoke the certificate. But I really don't like this idea because my chaincode would need to acquire a lot of node modules.


Right now I'm trying to see if I can get the certificates from the chaincode's environment (CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE etc.) because if I can do this, then the problem is solved. But I'm not very sure if it is good to use env. variables.